# When running docker-compose, I get a permission error

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, containers

I am new to deployment using docker so I believe that I am missing something vital here. I am trying to launch my app using docker/nginx and I have gotten to a stage where I am able to run the dev-environment as a container, but when I go to run the yml that I would use for deployment I get a `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'app/vol'` Error. That is to say I can run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build` and that provides me access to my app in the dev environment, but running `docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml up --build` causes the shown error message.

This is from following along a tutorial online but adding extra dependencies and content to the Django project. I have made a version identical to the tutorial and that works, and when I check what I have against that version, nothing seems to differ.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Terminal Error Output:

```
proxy_1                          | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
proxy_1                          | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
proxy_1                          | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
proxy_1                          | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: can not modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (read-only file system?)
proxy_1                          | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
proxy_1                          | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
proxy_1                          | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
proxy_1                          | 2021/06/10 17:23:34 [emerg] 1#1: invalid host in upstream "app:8000/" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9
proxy_1                          | nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "app:8000/" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9
app_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1  |   File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
app_1  |     main()
app_1  |   File "manage.py", line 19, in main
app_1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
app_1  |     utility.execute()
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
app_1  |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
app_1  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
app_1  |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 187, in handle
app_1  |     collected = self.collect()
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
app_1  |     handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 348, in copy_file
app_1  |     self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 54, in save
app_1  |     return self._save(name, content)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 255, in _save
app_1  |     os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
app_1  |     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
app_1  |     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
app_1  |     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
app_1  |   [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
app_1  |     mkdir(name, mode)
app_1  | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/vol'
```

My file structure:

```
app
├───proxy
|      ├───default.conf
|      ├───Dockerfile
|      └───uwsgi_params
├───scripts
|      └───entrypoint.sh
└───app
|
└───docker-compose-deploy.yml
|
└───docker-compose.yml
|
└───Dockerfile
|
└───requirements.txt
```

proxy/default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 8080;

    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass app:8000/;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

proxy/Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1-alpine

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./uwsgi_params /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /vol/static
RUN chmod 755 /vol/static

USER nginx
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
    app:
        build: 
            context: .
        ports: 
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes: 
            - ./app:/app
        command: sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
        environment: 
            - DEBUG=1
```

docker-compose-deploy.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services: 
    app:
        build: 
            context: .
        volumes: 
            - /static_data:/vol/web
        environment: 
            - SECRET_KEY=samplesecret123
            - ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1,localhost
    proxy:
        build:
            context: ./proxy
        volumes: 
            - /static_data:/vol/static
        ports: 
            - "8080:8080"
        depends_on: 
            - app

volumes: 
    static_data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

COPY ./requierments.txt /requierments.txt 
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp libc-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev gcc linux-headers

RUN pip install -r /requierments.txt
RUN apk del .tmp

RUN mkdir /syntiant_filesystem_companion
COPY ./syntiant_filesystem_companion /syntiant_filesystem_companion
WORKDIR /syntiant_filesystem_companion
COPY ./scripts /scripts

RUN chmod +x /scripts/*

RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/static

RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /vol
RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web
USER user

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

Django settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os, sys

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
#BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
#STATICFILES_DIRS = (
#  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
#)

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'changeme')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = bool(int(os.environ.get('DEBUG',0)))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV = os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS')
if ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(ALLOWED_HOSTS_ENV.split(','))


AUTH_USER_MODEL = "register.Account"


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    'register.apps.RegisterConfig',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/static/'
MEDIA_URL='/static/media/'

STATIC_ROOT='vol/web/static'
MEDIA_ROOT='vol/web/media'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK="bootstrap4"

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/'

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'django_project_name'))
```

I am very new to django/docker, so I am sure I am missing some boilerplate stuff. Any help in understanding the root cause of this issue would be very helpful as it is my understanding that what I am trying to do is fairly simple.

Comment: Since your error is `nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "app:8000/" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9`, do you have any sites called `app` defined in your `nginx`?

Comment: Where would this be defined? I have `app:8000` in the `default.conf` but other than that or the `docker-compose-deploy.yml` I don't have it in there as far as I am aware

Comment: I have found that changin `STATIC_ROOT='vol/web/static'` `MEDIA_ROOT='vol/web/media'`to `STATIC_ROOT='/vol/web/static'` `MEDIA_ROOT='/vol/web/media'` allows the build to finish and for workers to be launched. However, I get a 500 error with nothing much else from the console. I can see that `0 static files copied to '/vol/web/static', 131 unmodified` from the console which is concerning. Any thoughts on what might be causing this and/or if this is the correct approach?

Comment: Since your files have been copied before, I think `0 static files ...` is a normal message. I don't see any error log file in `python:3.8-alpine` image but if they are stored in your `proxy` container, exec into it and see your error log files of nginx to investigate more

Answer (score -2):

You should use a sudoer user and run your code as sudo user
This is the problem from OS which doesn't let your yml to start,
if not possible then you should change the code access/execute level using chmod +x (your file name) on the machine/container you need to run the code.
some times it works

Comment: I will be running this program from a terminal where I do not have sudo access, so I would like to avoid using sudo if at all possible.

Comment: then use chmod +x (your file name) on the machine and rerun